# GitHub: How to create pull request from forked repository to upstream repo only including some past commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I forked a template repository (T) on GitHub and did some work in my own repo (X) making use of the template.

Now repo X completely conflicts with repo T because of custom work I pushed to X.

Other than doing custom work with the template, I also did some improvements to the template.

I created a pull request but it contains all my past commits since forking. I want to include only template improvements (just a few commits in the middle of my commit history) in the pull request. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the template changes (improvement commits, that you want to [merge to the upstream repo with a pull-request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)) from your custom commits.

The better way is to use two different git repositories, but in case of you prefer to maintain only one you have to:

1. Backup your history, creating a new temp branch

   `git checkout -b tempmaster
   git checkout master # return to the previous one if master`
2. If you didn't it before, add the original template repository (T) as upstream remote: 

   `git remote add upstream https://github.com/...`
3. Fetch all remote changes

   `git fetch --all`
4. Hard reset your current branch to the upstream repository

   `git reset --hard upstream/master # if master`
5. Import your improvements commits ( `git cherry-pick` ) from the temp branch and fix conflicts.
6. Once finish, push the new "rebased" branch and create the pull-request
7. Now from this branch you can create your own custom branch `git checkout -b myapp` and import yours custom commits in the same way.

Once fixed, when you want to update your forked branch (master) with upstream changes, use rebase:
 `git rebase upstream/master`

Comment: I end up using separate repositories. I contacted GitHub support to detach forked repository and renamed it. Then I forked again to commit template changes. Thanks.